# Better Approach for Creating Temp Object for Core Data with Restkit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, restkit

In my app, I have this scenario where I need to post an object to remoter server and get an object key back and then store the object locally. I have Core data and Restkit implemented in my app.

The object value are collected from user input. I couldn't figure out a great way to prepare the object before posting it to remote server. This object is an entity of type NSManagedObject, and I don't want to store it before I get the object id from server.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896718/best-practice-for-temporary-objects-in-restkit-with-core-data) which suggested to use a transient object to handle this situation. But as discussed in that thread, this causes issue with code maintenance.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your core data model class adhere to the RKRequestSerializable protocol.

Then when the user input is validated, create an entity as normal and set it as the params value to the RKRequest, this will send your object as the HTTP body. Look inside RKParams.m for an example.

Also set the newly created entity as the targetObject for the RKObjectLoader. That way, when your web service returns the information (like the new unique ID), it will target the new object and save the new unique ID to this object without creating a duplicate.

Clear as mud?

PS: Oh and be careful mixing autogenerated core data classes with custom code! I recommend [mogen](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to help you not lose code each time you make a change.

Comment: I believe in RestKit 0.20 this should be now handled automatically by creating an RKEntityMapping and setting the parameter "identificationAttributes" to your (remote) identification parameter stored locally